# What is the difference between Custom Components and Composite Components?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component, custom-component

What is the difference between JSF Custom Components and Facelets Composite Components?

Answer (score 6):

JSF [custom components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnavg.html) are Java classes which extend [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html). Facelets [composite components](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giqzr.html) are XHTML files which use [`http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/tld-summary.html) namespace.

#### See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)