# JSF: p:dataTable with f:attribute results in "argument type mismatch" error

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to add conditionally add some arguments to a `p:dataTable` like described in [Conditionally render element's attribute in a composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897202/conditionally-render-elements-attribute-in-a-composite-component). But even without the `c:if` I get an `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch` ([Stacktrace on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SQxNAg6v)).

```
...
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
...

<p:dataTable var="r" value="#{myBean.values}" >
  <f:attribute name="paginator" value="true" />
</p:dataTable>
```

The error does not occur (and the paginator is available) if I add the attribute directly `<p:dataTable ... paginator="true">`. 
My environment is Primefaces 3.4.1 with JBoss 7.1.1-Final.

Comment: not sure about your approach, but I think you might tweak the following approach to your needs http://jdevelopment.nl/easily-disable-sorting-primefaces-3s-datatable/ its working great for the sorting... really a great article its written by Arjan Tijms , (BalusC co worker)!

Comment: Thank's interesting article. Currently I'm trying to solve a similar issue with filtering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing it as EL object:

```
<f:attribute name="paginator" value="#{true}" />
```