# javax.faces.component.UIData.getRows fails to parse 25 and 1000 as valid integer values

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am struggling hard to pass an `int` value to the attribute `rows`.

```
<p:dataTable rows="#{isLazy ? 25 : 1000}">
    <f:attribute name="selectionMode" value="#{widget.selectionMode}"/>
    <f:attribute name="selection" value="#{widget.selectionModel.selection}"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

The method from `javax.faces.component.UIData` that retrieves the value is defined as

```
public int getRows() {
    return (Integer) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.rows, 0);
}
```

`getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.rows, 0)` results in a `Long` and thereafter can't be cast to `Integer`.

1. Is there any way to tell the parser to treat the result of the expression `isLazy ? 25 : 1000` as an `int` or `Integer`?
2. Is it just me, or is that cast so poorly written?

<sub>I am new to JSF, any help would be appreciated.</sub>

---

UPDATE 1: **Surprisingly, it works (an `Integer` is returned) if I exclude all the `<f:attribute />`s from `p:dataTable`.** I am completely bewildered.

UPDATE 2: I've found an awful workaround. I could define a function in `facelet-taglib` referring to `Integer.valueOf(int)`

```
<function>
    <function-name>toInt</function-name>
    <function-class>java.lang.Integer</function-class>
    <function-signature>Integer valueOf(int)</function-signature>
</function>
```

and wrap up my value with it.

```
<f:attribute name="rows" value="#{bg:toInt(1000)}"/>
```

Comment: maybe instead of doing validation in p:dataTable you could call for a manage bean function? It's been a while since I played with JSF but that should work

Comment: @LukasNovicky sure, it could be refactored. The point is I can't put even a single `int` there - it will turn it into a `Long`

Comment: maybe that is something typical to primeFaces? I never worked with it - always used pure JSF and had no issue with passing int, Integers nor longs of any kind. sorry I cannot help you more

Comment: I'm bewildered there is no initial [mcve]... You mentioned the 'removal' of all `f:attribute` tags but there are none in your initial post... Please always, always, always create an [mcve]. Otherwise it is hard (next to impossible) to even try to reproduce... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009280/jsf-compositeattribute-with-fattribute-conversion-error

Comment: @Kukeltje I had removed them when I posted it because they seemed completely irrelevant. Updated

Comment: That is exectly what creating an [mcve] is for... remove **really, explicitly** irrelevant code before posting. Cheers...

Comment: @Kukeltje thank you, your links always make sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I called "an awful workaround" turned out to be the only working solution I've found.

I defined a function in `facelet-taglib` that refers to `Integer.valueOf(int)`

```
<function>
    <function-name>toInt</function-name>
    <function-class>java.lang.Integer</function-class>
    <function-signature>Integer valueOf(int)</function-signature>
</function>
```

and could wrap up an integer literal with it.

```
<f:attribute name="rows" value="#{bg:toInt(1000)}"/>
```

That definition litters my `facelet-taglib` and I kinda hate it, but it works.

**Helpful links:**

[JSF composite:attribute with f:attribute conversion error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009280/jsf-compositeattribute-with-fattribute-conversion-error)